# How to bind one of member functions of the same name in a class, with c++11 std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Test{
public:

    int work(){
        cout << "in work " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    void work(int x){
        //cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "in work..." << endl;
    }
};  

int main(){
    Test test;
    std::function<void()> f = std::bind(&Test::work, &test);
    thread th(f);
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

As above code, I want to bind member function `void work(void)` of a class (let's name it Test) , but occurs compiler error saying that can not determine which overrided function to use.

I can not change class Test since it belongs to a lib, how to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Prefer `auto f = [&test] { test.work(); };` to any bind expression

Comment: lambda is  indeed convenient than std::bind to realize my goal, after seeing these answers

Comment: Also note that by using `std::function` instead of `auto` you pay the price of type-erasure

Comment: remember that, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't skip `std::bind` altogether and use a lambda?

```
auto fp = [&t]() { t.test()};
```

As a bonus, your executable size will be smaller and your compiler has much easier time to inline the code if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, it works. simply because I'm not very familiar with c++11~

Answer (score 5):

By casting it to the correct type:

```
std::function<void()> f = std::bind( static_cast<int (Test::*)()>(&Test::work), &test);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that the solution doesn't work with compile error C2562: “std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__thiscall Test::* )(void),int,Test,>,Test *>,false>::_ApplyX”:“void”函数返回值 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 283

Answer (score 3):

When deducing the template arguments to bind, the compiler is not in a context that allows function overload resolution - to be simplistic about it, it hasn't got that far yet.

Having deduced that the first argument is indeed the name of a member function pointer, it finds that there are two functions of the same name but of different types.

At this stage, they're both equally valid candidates (from the point of template argument deduction), therefore it's ambiguous

A static cast disambiguates because we're pushing the compiler beyond the stage where it has to deduce a template type - we have taken on the responsibility to template type deduction ourselves - by specifying the type in the `static_cast`.

So now all it has to do is overload resolution.

```
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
public:

    int work(){
        cout << "in work " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    void work(int x){
        //cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "in work..." << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Test test;

    // only overload resolution required here 
    auto fp = static_cast<int (Test::*)()>(&Test::work);

    // type is now unambiguous and overload resolution is already done
    std::function<void()> f = std::bind(fp, &test);

    thread th(f);
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that the solution doesn't work with compile error `C2562: “std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__thiscall Test::* )(void),int,Test,>,Test *>,false>::_ApplyX”:“void”函数返回值 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 283 `

Comment: is visual studio 12 fully c++11-compliant?

Answer (score 1):

try this(member function ptr):

```
int main(){
    Test test;
    typedef int(Test:: *WKPtr)(void);
    WKPtr p = &Test::work;
    std::function<int()> f = std::bind(p, &test);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```